# Lwuit S40 Dimmed Forms

Tags: lwuit, nokia-s40, lwuit-dialog

I am developing a LWUIT S40 app. The guidelines specify that when a
dialog is on, the background, including status bar,
header bar, category bar, must be dimmed – 60%
black.

I think that this will happen automatically, but it doesn't.

Anybody knows a way to do that? To dim the header bar and the category bar, like this capture (which is an lcdui alert)

[image: LCDUI ALERT].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use native Alert from nokia LCDUI. the LWUIT for Series 40 allow us to combine the LCDUI component along with LWUIT component.

For example, here's my code:

```
Alert loading = new Alert("MIG33", "Loading user", null, null);
loading.setIndicator(new Gauge(null, false, Gauge.INDEFINITE, Gauge.CONTINUOUS_RUNNING));
javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(loading);
```

Since LWUIT has its own Display class we use in the midlet. It has to be written like above. So it can be differenced with the Display from LCDUI.

Comment: I don't find a better solution, but I shouldn't use lcdui alerts

Comment: Why shouldn't? I think it's the better part of LWUIT for Series 40. You still can combine the LCDUI and the LWUIT. LWUIT after all, is a higher level than LCDUI Canvas too, doesn't it? :D

Comment: Yeah but my project managers force me to do everything using only the LWUIT library

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the tint color of the parent form to something like `0xaa000000` (an ARGB value to paint the background).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shai, but can you give me some code lines?
I have the form, but i can't get the parent form(all the screen, with hedaer and categorybar)

Comment: You mean they used the native OS title on the S40 port? Well that's what you get as a result...

Comment: S40 port is what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I dont think LWUIT S40 gives access to the header bar and the category bar, you need to get app Nokia signed to edit category bar colors. For me i customized the loading dialog and set the title like this : dialogObj.setTitle(" ");  so nothing appears in the dialog title.

Also for an app using the category bar, instead of this approach i refresh the form's contents with the loading GIF or APNG and any loading message as well.